# Assigning the rownnum values in a column in the table in ORACLE database?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, rownum

Example:
**It does not work.**

```
UPDATE column_name SET rownum FROM table_name
```

**This work!**

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = rownum;
```

**This works but the update is performed incorrectly**

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY column_name;
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = rownum;
```

**I wish the following update behavior:**
**Note:'rownum ' It is not a physical column of the table**

```
/*
pc_comentario = tableName
cod_comentario = columnName (Reference column for sorting)
dtc_andamento = columnDay (Reference column to update the "columnName" according to the order of this column)
*/

rownum | columnName | columnDay

1            1          day 1
2            5          day 5
3            7          day 2
```

After change with update

```
rownum | columnName (Update this column) | columnDay (sort by this column)

  1                    1                           day 1
  2                    2                           day 2
  3                    3                           day 5
```

**ALMOST DONE!** this column 'cod_comentario_1 "which was materialized in RAM is correct. I need this column" cod_comentario_1 "that does not exist in the table is acknowledged in the consultations with java.

```
SELECT cod_comentario, dtc_andamento, cod_processo ,
  ROW_NUMBER()
    OVER (PARTITION BY cod_processo
          ORDER BY dtc_andamento) cod_comentario_1
FROM pc_comentario
```

[image]

**upadate do not work this way:**

```
UPDATE (
SELECT cod_processo
  ROW_NUMBER()
    OVER (PARTITION BY cod_processo
          ORDER BY dtc_andamento)cod_comentario_1
FROM pc_comentario
) SET cod_comentario_1) 
order by Seq
```

**I must enter the values of this consultation in a new column that I created**

```
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER()
    OVER (PARTITION BY cod_processo
          ORDER BY dtc_andamento DESC)  
FROM pc_comentario
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. thank you Praveen and Rahul. It is possible to make this update operation based on a specific orndemento? because in case the change is held in a default order. It does not work : UPDATE TABLE_NAME  SET COLUMN_NAME = rownum ORDER by dtc_andamento;

Comment: so that a row is the last visit, I must create a procedure for the case? I experienced execute two instructions at once in SQL Developer, but not worked. the ordering of rownum is standard and not as specified in the order by.

I tried to do this by running at the same time and did not work:

SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY column_name;
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = rownum;

Comment: Do you have a primary key on the table? If try `merge`. In the `using` clause select the PK and `row_number() .. as RN.`. Match on PK and when matched update with RN. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9016.htm

Comment: Thanks Shannon. The planning "dtc_andamento" must match "cod_comentario" but the lines of each records are not combined. I would have to do an UPDATE with the COLUMN_NUMBER and consultation of the final order by cod_comentario "(which is the name of a column) or" dtc_andamento? "(also the name of a column)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be like below rather; I believe `UPDATE` statement has no `FROM` clause

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = rownum;
```

Again, it will work only if `rownum` is an existing column in your table. If you are trying to use Oracle `rownum` instead then consider using `row_number()` function rather

```
update table_name set column_name = 
select rn from ( select column_name, row_number() over (order by column_name) rn  
           from table_name ) xx;
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul, but have a error: 00921. 00000 -  "unexpected end of SQL command"
*Cause: BLANK
*Action: BLANK   .Who is 'xx' and 'm'? rn is rowName?  I'm trying to use Oracle rownum, rownum is not a physical column of the my table

Comment: Similar with UPDATE: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm

Comment: but gostarai applying the update, because the column "dtc_andamento" is not ordered.It needs to do an update every time this query is executed.I not found in the documentation on the update of use along with oreder by and column_number ()

Comment: SELECT cod_comentario, dtc_andamento, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cod_comentario ORDER BY dtc_andamento) AS dtc_andamento FROM pc_comentario;

Comment: @PauloVictor, there was a missing `)` and so the error. edited my answer ... try now.

Comment: I had realized '(', but the error is not related to it. What would be "rn" and "xx" in your query?

Comment: @PauloVictor, `rn` is the column alias and `xx` is the table or inline view alias. You should try the edited query in answer and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET column_name = rownum
```

Comment: Thanks Praveen. it's worked this part! i need sorting and update. view the details the question, please. I modified.

Answer (score 0):

As you state yourself, `rownum` is a virtual column. It assigns a sequential value to each row of a *particular result set*. Which means that the row number of a row could be completely different in the result set of a different query.

If you really want to show the row number as part of the result set, specify it as you would any column:

```
select rownum as columnName, columnDay
from   table
order by ...;
```